# Gimbal beacon service error on iOS SDK

Tags: ios, service, bluetooth

I'm trying to start the  Gimbal beacon service and I get the following error.

```
Error Domain=QLRestTemplateErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x15cd5120 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.getfyx.com/api/mbr/v1/receivers, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.getfyx.com/api/mbr/v1/receivers, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x14e3d590 "The request timed out."}
```

Does anyone know what produces this kind of error?

Comment: Yes not have an active internet connection or host is down.

Answer (score 0):

As rckoenes suggets, this error appears when I try to start the service and there is no internet connection.